# Sending Gmail from Local Host

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using the Acquia stack on my localhost (running Vista) and am trying unsuccessfully to send emails. I want to send them via Gmail, and have tried all sorts of settings in the php.ini file. There are no error messages, but no email is delivered. I've gotten no response on the Acquia forum, so I was hoping someone here might be able to help. Thanks very much.

Comment: You might have better luck on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

You need http://drupal.org/project/phpmailer or http://drupal.org/project/smtp because you need to authenticate to Google's SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server your hosting on you can use MSMTP to completely bypass the internal mailing system (sendmail) and use your external provider at the system level.  There's a tutorial on it here:

http://floatsolutions.com/blog/2009/12/avoid-complicated-sendmail-setup-using-msmtp-sendmail-emulator/